# table extracted from pdf including header and subheader, and need to add a column based on header value

Tags: python, pdf

I need to extract table information from pdf file, it contains the header and subheader. I used python tabula package and it gives me something like this:

| Header | unnanmed1 | unnamed2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| subheader1 | subheader2 | subheader3 |
| A | nan | nan |
| 1 | aaa | bbb |
| 2 | ccc | ddd |
| 3 | eee | fff |
| B | nan | nan |
| 4 | ggg | hhh |
| 5 | iii | jjj |
| 6 | kkk | lll |

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    NaN = np.nan
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Header': ['subheader1', 'A', 1, 2, 3, 'B', 4, 5, 6],
        'unnanmed1': ['subheader2', NaN, 'aaa', 'ccc', 'eee', NaN, 
    'ggg', 'iii', 'kkk'],
        'unnamed2': ['subheader3', NaN, 'bbb', 'ddd', 'fff', NaN, 
    'hhh', 'jjj', 'lll'],
    })
```

so, what I need to get is to get this result:

| Header | subheader1 | subheader2 | subheader3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | aaa | bbb |
| A | 2 | ccc | ddd |
| A | 3 | eee | fff |
| B | 4 | ggg | hhh |
| B | 5 | iii | jjj |
| B | 6 | kkk | lll |

I consider using map to do so, but still do not have a very clear clue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with some hard code to solve this problem. But if anyone can provide a more efficient approach, I will very much appreciate it. Thank you.

```
    df = df.rename(columns = {"Header": "subheader1", "unnanmed1": 
    "subheader2", "unnamed2": "subheader3"})
    df['Header'] = NaN
    df1 = df.drop([0])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop = True)
    
    nan_row_index = df1[df1['subheader3'].isna()]
    nan_row_index = nan_row_index.index.values
    if nan_row_index[-1] < df1.index.values[-1]:
        nan_row_index_final = np.append(nan_row_index, 
    df1.index.values[-1])
    else:
        nan_row_index_final = nan_row_index
    
    for i in range(len(nan_row_index_final)):
        if nan_row_index_final[i] == df1.index.values[-1]:
            print("out of range")
            break
        else:
            print(nan_row_index_final[i])
        for j in range(nan_row_index_final[i],nan_row_index_final[i+1]+1):
            df1.iloc[j, 3] = df1.iloc[nan_row_index_final[i],0]
    df1 = df1.dropna().reset_index(drop = True)
```